# Search record with apostrophe in mysql like query

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query something like this.

```
SELECT * from users where username LIKE "%test\'s%"
```

And have `users` database table with field name `username`.

And there is 1 record in `users` table with username `test\'s` and now i want to fire query for fetch record from users table according to `username`. but it's not working.

Please help me to come out from this issues.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: `And there is 1 record in users table with username test\'s` --> if this is causing problem Escape the apostrophe/single quote.

Comment: Do you _really_ have `test\'s` in your database? And if so, _why_ ...? It should be `test's`.

Comment: @CBroe ya i have `test\'s` in database.

Comment: Again: _Why_? That makes little sense. If you want to put that data into another context where this kind of escaping is necessary after reading it from your database, then you should do the escaping at that moment when you put it into that context. Escaped data in the database is bad design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i had same problem and i solved it using below code.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE `username` = 'test\\''s'
```

Hope this will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

SQL syntax should be:

```
SELECT * from users where username LIKE '%test''s%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE CONCAT('%', 'test\\\'s', '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from users where username = 'test''s'
```