# Apostrophe LIKE search in MYSQL not working

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL database, the title row is this:

```
Interview: Gus O\'Connor win
```

I am trying to search

```
title LIKE '%O\'Connor%'
```

I tried everything and still came up empty, no results returned.

I have tried

```
'%O''Connor%'
```

and

```
\"%O'Connor%"\
```

and yes, i am protecting myself from sql injection with code above.

Comment: Possible related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337610/search-record-with-apostrophe-in-mysql-like-query

Comment: The title row is exactly `Interview: Gus O\'Connor win`? You have a bogus back slash in your data?

Comment: yes, in my database, that is how it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
title LIKE "%O\\'Connor%"
```

Comment: That worked! Now a way to use it as a variable and replace the apostrophe with \\

Comment: @eberswine:- You can use the Replace function like this:- REPLACE(value, '\'', '\\'); Check:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1):

If your database entry actually contains that backslash, you'll need to use this:

```
title LIKE "%O\\'Connor%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are setting up a SQL string like this given the new PDO frame work which does allow not this syntax but anyways, try

```
 LIKE "%O\\'Connor%"
```